# What should I do to make java output the XML?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, jaxb, output

I'm making my homework and I have a bit of trouble here. Here's the deal: I had to make a C# program that communicates with a Java endpoint. I was trying to set up a Java web app, where the user can give some info and register to the service. At first, my thought was to get the Java App generate an XML from the user, then the C# app could download the file if needed and then tweak it.

So I made a Class lets call it Guest, with some datafields. Then I made a GuestContainer singleton class for all the registered guests with an ArrayList in it, that contains all the guests. If a guest is added, the GuestContainer should make an XML file from them. Everything seems working except Java is not making any file...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement; 


@XmlRootElement(name = "guest")
public class Guest{

    private String name;

    private String city;

    private String phoneNumber;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "city")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "phoneNumber")
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public Guest(String name, String city, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
```

My GuestContainer:

```
package Model;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
import javanet.staxutils.XMLStreamEventWriter;
import javax.xml.bind.*;


public class GuestContainer{

    private ArrayList<Guest> guests;
    private static GuestContainer container;
    private JAXBContext context;
    private Marshaller _m;

    public static GuestContainer getInstance() throws JAXBException{

        if (container == null) {
            container = new GuestContainer();
        }

        return container;
    }

    private GuestContainer() throws JAXBException{

        this.guests = new ArrayList<Guest>();
        this.context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Guest.class);
        this._m = this.context.createMarshaller();
        this._m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    }

    public void AddGuest(Guest guest) throws JAXBException, 
        FileNotFoundException{

        guests.add(guest);
        MakeFile();
    }
    private void MakeFile() throws PropertyException, JAXBException, 
            FileNotFoundException{

        for (Guest guest : this.guests) {
            ///guest.ToXML(file);
            _m.marshal(guest, new File("guests.xml"));

        }
    }
```

So I want to get an XML output where all the guests is there, but unfortunatelly I don't have any errors neither any XML.

Comment: You would only get the latest guest in the file, as the Javadoc states: ``XML will be written to this file. If it already exists, it will be overwritten.``

Comment: If I add the file to the project folder. It's still empty. I added in every folder to just to be sure...None of them got overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `GuestContainer` an `XmlRootElement`, then add all your `Guest` and marshal the `GuestContainer` after that:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class GuestContainer
{
    private ArrayList<Guest> guests;
    private static GuestContainer container;
    @XmlTransient
    private JAXBContext context;
    @XmlTransient
    private Marshaller _m;

    public static GuestContainer getInstance() throws JAXBException
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            container = new GuestContainer();
        }
        return container;
    }

    private GuestContainer() throws JAXBException
    {
        this.guests = new ArrayList<Guest>();
        this.context = JAXBContext.newInstance(GuestContainer.class);
        this._m = this.context.createMarshaller();
        this._m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    }

    public void addGuest(Guest guest) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        guests.add(guest);
    }

    @XmlElement(name="guest")
    public ArrayList<Guest> getGuests()
    {
        return guests;
    }

    public void makeFile() throws PropertyException, JAXBException, IOException
    {
        _m.marshal(this, new File("guests.xml"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            GuestContainer.getInstance().addGuest(new Guest("testName", "testCity", "testPhone"));
            GuestContainer.getInstance().addGuest(new Guest("test2", "testVillage", "testFax"));
            GuestContainer.getInstance().addGuest(new Guest("testAbc", "testTown", "testMail"));
            GuestContainer.getInstance().makeFile();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to dump your elements into the file, use a `FileOutputStream` and append your elements:

```java
private void makeFile() throws PropertyException, JAXBException, IOException
{
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("d:/tmp/guests.xml", true))
    {
        if(guests.size()==1)
            _m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, false);
        else
            _m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);

        _m.marshal(guests.get(guests.size() - 1), out);
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be great, but i have to make the file on the "server" like in the root directory of my Web project. Then if the localhost:8080 is open and running, i could download that XML into my c# app. Well Java is making the file.

Comment: You can create the XML on the fly in a servlet.